# laravel 5.4 not working on subdomain

Tags: laravel, subdomain, laravel-5.4, http-status-code-500

Steps I followed till now:

1. create sub-domain.
2. uploaded project files of public inside public_html/subdomain-name/
3. create a folder subdomain-name in root
4. upload every files of laravel project except public folder inside subdomain-name folder
5. change 2 lines of `index.php` which is inside public_html/subdomain-name/ as to:

`require __DIR__.'/../../../staging/bootstrap/autoload.php';`

and

`$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../../staging/bootstrap/app.php';`

And my htaccess files looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I am getting error as:

`This page isn’t working
staging.mydomain.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500`

Can somebody guide me with this? Thank You

Comment: Check your Apache/2 Error_log

Comment: what is the reason for downvote?

Comment: I didn't down vote.

Comment: .@YvanWatchman I am using shared hosting. I don't have access to apache error log. is there any idea? sorry I didn't mean to you. for whom whom downvote the question

Comment: Which hosting platform such as DirectAdmin, CPanel, Plesk.

Comment: they provide me cpanel

Comment: There is a button 'Errors' in your UI. Click and view the errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164762/discussion-between-vijayrana-and-yvan-watchman).

Answer (score 0):

***2. uploaded project files of public inside public_html/subdomain-name/***

When you create a subdomain, a folder appears in your root directory, you should upload project files of public into created subdomain folder. ie (example.your site.com) and not into public_HTML/subdomain

You should also try this in your .htaccess

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```